Laravel Relationship define to query
table products

id
type (ITEM, SUB_ITEM)
name

table product_relations

id
main_product_id
parent_product_id
child_product_id
price

main_product_id always type ITEM
parent_product_id can be ITEM or SUB_ITEM
child_product_id always SUB_ITEM
SUB_ITEM can have SUB_ITEM
class ProductController extends Controller{
public function getProducts()
{
   $query = Product::query();
    $query = $query->with(['sub_products' => function ($q) {
$q->with(['product' => function ($q) {
    $q->with(['sub_products' => function ($q) {
        $q->where('main_product_id', $this->id)  // Always use the top-level product ID
        ->with('product');
    }]);
}])->where('main_product_id', $this->id); id}]);
    return response()->json($query );
}}

Product model
public function sub_products($main_product_id = null)
{
    return $this->hasMany(ProductRelation::class, 'parent_product_id', 'id')->when($main_product_id, function ($q) use ($main_product_id) {
        $q->where('main_product_id', $main_product_id);
    });
}

Now from the controller i need all product and their relation based on the product_relations table
ITEM -> SUB_ITEM -> SUB_ITEM
main_product_id => is to understand which product relation is this when relation btween SUB_ITEM with SUB_ITEM
Expecting result
[{
"id": 2148,
"type": "ITEM",
"name": "Wings 5pc",
"sub_products": [
  {
    "id": 143,
    "main_product_id": 2148,
    "parent_product_id": 2148,
    "child_product_id": 2153,
    "price": 2.5,
    "product": {
      "id": 2153,
      "type": "SUB_ITEM",
      "short_name": "Meal Deal Chips",
      "sub_products": [
        {
          "id": 144,
          "main_product_id": 2148,
          "parent_product_id": 2153,
          "child_product_id": 2154,
          "price": 0,
          "product": {
            "id": 2154,
            "type": "SUB_ITEM",
            "name": "Lemon"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]}]

the code i submitted the way i tried but failling.
Thanks

Instead of product_relations, this can be done using a single table categories in which  having a column as Id, name, parent_id.
